# How to keep active sheet immutable from its first occurrence

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am currently invoking the following code

```
Property Get wsSrc() As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
End Property
```

However, the way my module works is that the program jumps back and forth between sheets to copy and paste data. So whenever I need to go back to the source sheet, the module is setting the active sheet as the destination sheet since that's what was just modified.
Here is an example of how it works. and how the destination sheet is defined.

```
Sub PasteRI()
 Dim c As Range, cDest As Range

    
    Set c = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Rental Income", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
    
    Set cDest = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'next paste destination. 
    
    If c Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() 
        cDest.Resize(6, 1).Value = "-"       'fill placeholders
    Else
        c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 6).Copy    'got match - copy range
        cDest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
              Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is how the wsdest Book is defined

```
  Property Get wsDest() As Worksheet
        Set wsDest = Workbooks("DataLake.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    End Property
```

How should I change my definition of wsSrc? Its defined before the main sub.

Comment: Seems like you don't really need that `Property Get wsSrc` and you should just get a reference to `ActiveSheet` in the main sub.  Putting it in a Property just obscures the fact that it's not a fixed sheet.

Comment: I see, then could it be accessed by other subs that are being called? would I need to define it as a Dim in each sub or could i just call it?

Comment: You can pass it as a parameter.

Comment: `Dim ws As Worksheet:  Set ws = ActiveSheet` then use `ws`